# Akka custom supervisor not taking effect

Tags: scala, akka, akka-supervision, akka-actor

In src/main/resources/application.conf

```
actor {
  # The guardian "/user" will use this class to obtain its supervisorStrategy.
  # It needs to be a subclass of akka.actor.SupervisorStrategyConfigurator.
  # In addition to the default there is akka.actor.StoppingSupervisorStrategy.
  guardian-supervisor-strategy = "config.ResilientSupervisorStrategy"
}
```

which refers to the following:

```
package config

import akka.actor._
import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy._

final class ResilientSupervisorStrategy extends SupervisorStrategyConfigurator {
  override def create(): SupervisorStrategy = {
    OneForOneStrategy(){
      case _: ActorInitializationException ⇒ Stop
      case _: ActorKilledException         ⇒ Stop
      case _: DeathPactException           ⇒ Stop
      case _: Exception                    ⇒ Resume}
    }
  }
}
```

My Actor is instantiated like so

```
object Singleton {
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("main")
  val logger: ActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new Logger()))
}
```

and

```
val miner: ActorRef = 
    Singleton.actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new Miner()))
```

However, when `miner` hits an Exception, it still restarts (it is still using the default supervisor strategy)

---

As a side note, my actors have very simple internal state. All failures are due to external resources (ie. Futures not returned because the server sent a bad response) so the default strategy of restarting the actor is not necessary.

Comment: Can you show the code where your actors are instantiated?

Comment: I added the instantiation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be

```
akka.actor {
  # The guardian "/user" will use this class to obtain its supervisorStrategy.
  # It needs to be a subclass of akka.actor.SupervisorStrategyConfigurator.
  # In addition to the default there is akka.actor.StoppingSupervisorStrategy.
  guardian-supervisor-strategy = "config.ResilientSupervisorStrategy"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for mistakes in the class rather than the config.

Comment: It still crashes. I tried `akka { actor { ... } }` too. I think I need to look into the location of the application.conf file. Maybe related to the classpath

Comment: The other problem was an IntelliJ config problem. I had to mark the folder as a Resources folder, which also meant that it had to be moved outside of the src/main folder

Comment: Thanks for coming back with the complete solution. Did you create it as an sbt project? Intellij usually sets all that stuff up correctly

Comment: It is a sbt project, but every time I restart IntelliJ, I have to manually mark the src and resources folder. Is there a folder naming convention that I have to follow for IntelliJ to detect these things?